# How can I redirect from one subdomain to another on route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, subdomain, amazon-route53

I can't understand why this won't work. I own a domain example.com and 2 subdomains, app.example.com and donate.example.com. I want donate.example.com to redirect to app.example.com/donate.

I have set up a CNAME record in route 53 with name donate.example.com and value app.example.com/donate. The result is that I get "donate.example.com"s IP address cannot be found.

What is the correct way to accomplish this within route 53?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain Names consist of the part *before* the slash.

A domain name resolves to an IP address. Anything after the slash is interpreted by the app listening on that IP address.

You can certainly define `donate.example.com` as pointing to `app.example.com` by using a `CNAME` entry, but you *cannot* point to something with a slash, since that isn't part of the domain.

You would need a web server or proxy listening on `app.example.com` that can redirect or forward the request.